# Occurences of primes in pi

Tags: prime-numbers, pi

I've found an old math puzzle in my notes, and I can't seem to figure it out: List out the primes under $100,000$ and find the first occurrence of each of these primes in $\pi$. What is the *last* prime you'll find? [Visual Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4K59.png)

As we can see in the image, the first prime we see is $14159$, then we see $41$, then $4159$, and so on.

Clarification: by *last*, I mean *farthest/most number of digits from the decimal point*

Comment: +1, but I don't think there's a way to solve this problem that's faster than writing a script to do it.

Comment: Thanks - because it's such a strange problem I assumed I might have to write a script.

Comment: I would not think most people would be able to produce, say, the first few million (decimal) digits of $\pi,$ and this might still not be enough. I suggest that this was intended as just a thought question.

Comment: Also, it is not known for certain that $\pi$ is normal; it is conceivable that some finite strings of decimal digits never occur in the decimal expansion of $\pi$

Comment: True, $\pi$ is not known to be normal, but it is known that every digit sequence of length $11$ or less occurs somewhere in $\pi$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last (the farthest) prime number of this list is $35569$; its distance of decimal point is $715492$.
So, there is enough to have $1000000$ first digits of $\pi$ to reach the result.

Its place: $...2347781619751257278515\color{red}{35569}8616...$

Here is the (incomplete) list of first prime numbers occurrence distances:

```
2   6
3   9
5   4
7   13
11  94
13  110
17  95
19  37
23  16
29  186
31  137
37  46
41  2
43  23
47  119
53  8
59  4
61  219
67  98
71  39
73  299
79  13
83  26
89  11
97  12
101 852
103 3486
107 1487
109 206
113 362
127 297
131 1096
137 859
139 525
149 2606
151 393
157 1657
163 1410
167 1182
173 428
179 438
181 728
191 1944
193 168
197 37
199 704
211 93
223 135
227 484
229 185
233 229
239 1688
241 1707
251 1713
257 1006
263 613
269 1393
271 241
277 558
281 789
283 1090
293 571
307 64
311 845
313 858
317 137
331 1127
337 230
347 1092
349 760
353 934
359 142
367 349
373 5229
379 457
383 25
389 1077
397 2978
401 1197
409 339
419 36
421 92
431 2119
433 23
439 2301
443 2085
449 1249
457 2783
461 218
463 530
467 582
479 1093
487 2648
491 293
499 761
503 837
509 1146
521 172
523 578
541 1112
547 1406
557 1101
563 1210
569 1328
571 2847
577 624
587 304
593 213
599 1072
601 1217
607 286
613 970
617 886
619 842
631 312
641 1423
643 22
647 118
653 7
659 212
661 969
673 467
677 1306
683 2018
691 893
701 166
709 120
719 540
727 405
733 506
739 1692
743 2492
751 47
757 631
761 3547
769 2069
773 1066
787 647
797 1259
809 1002
811 152
821 101
823 113
827 619
829 334
839 2019
853 677
857 473
859 798
863 928
877 4142
881 204
883 1822
887 1753
907 542
911 1533
919 416
929 1853
937 45
941 391
947 2055
953 418
967 1400
971 38
977 738
983 501
991 1532
997 2241
1009    1816
1013    8270
1019    15482
1021    2749
1031    3494
1033    3486
1039    23646
1049    2238
1051    442
1061    43971
1063    17029
1069    41789
1087    10281
1091    6123
1093    14026
1097    206
1103    3493
1109    3253
1117    153
1123    6547
1129    4449
1151    26997
1153    33525
1163    2458
1171    25231
1181    11914
1187    7721
1193    3735
1201    243
1213    47501
1217    11077
1223    9549
1229    30417
1231    9450
1237    1924
1249    1080
1259    23662
1277    18047
1279    11307
1283    33126
1289    31065
1291    7876
1297    2632
1301    6320
1303    9107
1307    5591
1319    21020
1321    16563
1327    3794
1361    1653
1367    1304
1373    10886
1381    6278
1399    13014
1409    9319
1423    9270
1427    2666
1429    2121
1433    1696
1439    13137
1447    4960
1451    2685
1453    3186
1459    3237
1471    3325
1481    14934
1483    17978
1487    22100
1489    4455
1493    8241
1499    34985
1511    393
1523    2688
1531    29138
1543    9430
1549    26816
1553    17192
1559    2215
1567    3000
1571    4597
1579    3354
1583    16842
1597    10118
1601    7268
1607    4648
1609    396
1613    1651
1619    15174
1621    32910
1627    4746
1637    3660
1657    25386
1663    15597
1667    10496
1669    4653
1693    40
1697    6193
1699    7757
1709    11457
1721    1419
1723    6805
1733    11213
1741    16566
1747    8223
1753    2187
1759    25301
1777    11732
1783    11505
1787    646
1789    13043
1801    12256
1811    7432
1823    11891
1831    11184
1847    27917
1861    424
1867    6530
1871    2776
1873    3318
1877    27626
1879    6150
1889    13071
1901    23404
1907    541
1913    3826
1931    843
1933    13811
1949    495
1951    5030
1973    1641
1979    2905
1987    8690
1993    36605
1997    30171
1999    11196
2003    25410
2011    5774
2017    8897
2027    1513
2029    22246
2039    1911
2053    3329
2063    15877
2069    18990
2081    14769
2083    877
2087    2582
2089    76
2099    1728
2111    3991
2113    757
2129    711
2131    3901
2137    3042
2141    20492
2143    23786
2153    17955
2161    6796
2179    546
2203    1910
2207    2372
2213    4564
2221    1735
2237    4638
2239    8492
2243    16403
2251    1840
2267    2412
2269    3944
2273    14905
2281    19456
2287    2551
2293    16362
2297    20379
2309    4399
2311    2738
2333    28466
2339    9551
2341    7342
2347    7080
2351    7549
2357    15070
2371    1925
2377    15984
2381    13999
2383    11958
2389    12937
2393    15629
2399    7662
2411    2495
2417    13786
2423    18340
2437    3783
2441    2308
2447    19235
2459    2227
2467    40831
2473    536
2477    4905
2503    6417
2521    2425
2531    13840
2539    10874
2543    9401
2549    2433
2551    1569
2557    28708
2579    53160
2591    6169
2593    27662
2609    2282
2617    9116
2621    14034
2633    11789
2647    7976
2657    4136
2659    7635
2663    24262
2671    2051
2677    15675
2683    42129
2687    33724
2689    13112
2693    33928
2699    1393
2707    20894
2711    6801
2713    8918
2719    13093
2729    24050
2731    13234
2741    24756
2749    462
2753    5506
2767    55627
2777    5321
2789    6553
2791    1785
2797    16369
2801    3416
2803    83
2819    3335
2833    3581
2837    20588
2843    4686
2851    13521
2857    15047
2861    1441
2879    24382
2887    2528
2897    3243
2903    12579
2909    5765
2917    6086
2927    8682
2939    5845
2953    1124
2957    27383
2963    53925
2969    8929
2971    8586
2999    21578
3001    972
3011    492
3019    1045
3023    10714
3037    28839
3041    6458
3049    16684
3061    4169
3067    1900
3079    10903
3083    11149
3089    3621
3109    4033
3119    29707
3121    20088
3137    858
3163    3584
3167    17445
3169    22923
3181    5313
3187    7291
3191    2871
3203    3767
3209    33397
3217    959
3221    12811
3229    6571
3251    3146
3253    10092
3257    31877
3259    3738
3271    4739
3299    21169
3301    11430
3307    11152
3313    1302
3319    31079
3323    1686
3329    11791
3331    8828
3343    11351
3347    1667
3359    14848
3361    7350
3371    7185
3373    13261
3389    7652
3391    5588
3407    5513
3413    15822
3433    10694
3449    1507
3457    11543
3461    4108
3463    11694
3467    3076
3469    811
3491    5792
3499    760
3511    1347
3517    25491
3527    5895
3529    8584
3533    11128
3539    3446
3541    18616
3547    1405
3557    43726
3559    2480
3571    6113
3581    7274
3583    6968
3593    7046
3607    285
3613    12913
3617    24957
3623    2759
3631    15908
3637    642
3643    346
3659    10264
3671    28646
3673    504
3677    1305
3691    16236
3697    42419
3701    5103
3709    9404
3719    539
3727    6199
3733    13063
3739    42253
3761    4411
3767    7567
3769    18216
3779    4808
3793    8338
3797    1258
3803    24499
3821    13418
3823    3730
3833    9561
3847    14361
3851    6396
3853    4714
3863    5328
3877    5331
3881    3027
3889    16351
3907    1689
3911    3733
3917    8446
3919    1913
3923    14195
3929    1852
3931    1163
3943    24327
3947    6816
3967    58248
3989    6577
4001    22056
4003    37207
4007    12403
4013    2078
4019    9843
4021    9022
4027    8008
4049    14941
4051    595
4057    65905
4073    15181
4079    6103
4091    339
4093    9892
4099    14006
4111    12699
4127    296
4129    34129
4133    7183
4139    14193
4153    11046
4157    7344
4159    2
4177    21135
4201    701
4211    92
4217    28506
4219    7604
4229    4796
4231    2994
4241    1878
4243    12188
4253    7337
4259    1290
4261    10286
4271    2743
4273    2405
4283    29481
4289    13058
4297    4514
4327    18893
4337    5976
4339    22950
4349    22021
4357    9432
4363    7100
4373    13062
4391    9857
4397    10030
4409    655
4421    3477
4423    7591
4441    51025
4447    2707
4451    39827
4457    2845
4463    9243
4481    40589
4483    30110
4493    23285
4507    5447
4513    6110
4517    2107
4519    6299
4523    14432
4547    1701
4549    3114
4561    4242
4567    5295
4583    23347
4591    3238
4597    27047
4603    262
4621    11287
4637    1155
4639    530
4643    5493
4649    1159
4651    9065
4657    1956
4663    13470
4673    15252
4679    15476
4691    9884
4703    7905
4721    4771
4723    15665
4729    45915
4733    4263
4751    20415
4759    33567
4783    3888
4787    9526
4789    10658
4793    9138
4799    19746
4801    4552
4813    29016
4817    20604
4831    17577
4861    266
4871    23729
4877    7883
4889    3682
4903    3773
4909    2607
4919    1616
4931    5705
4933    14846
4937    2772
4943    12547
4951    10551
4957    3906
4967    6614
4969    6180
4973    6638
4987    1509
4993    5305
4999    761
5003    11644
5009    21029
5011    4447
5021    15570
5023    4873
5039    6418
5051    39900
5059    9786
5077    5448
5081    3205
5087    24680
5099    25418
5101    8616
5107    10239
5113    31662
5119    16140
5147    3324
5153    58023
5167    5032
5171    3538
5179    5726
5189    1714
5197    21191
5209    325
5227    3987
5231    2737
5233    1684
5237    2689
5261    840
5273    18940
5279    6467
5281    30052
5297    8248
5303    7325
5309    419
5323    11048
5333    22748
5347    11174
5351    11531
5381    5037
5387    12670
5393    10594
5399    10870
5407    6102
5413    5278
5417    8517
5419    4954
5431    6860
5437    9402
5441    3960
5443    9028
5449    6778
5471    4010
5477    1702
5479    18556
5483    10667
5501    6697
5503    6878
5507    3588
5519    10584
5521    1663
5527    6466
5531    17193
5557    1450
5563    8723
5569    9619
5573    4003
5581    4072
5591    11168
5623    9684
5639    6575
5641    9396
5647    4049
5651    5724
5653    20005
5657    9161
5659    2453
5669    256
5683    10486
5689    11009
5693    26352
5701    7698
5711    6114
5717    31738
5737    11545
5741    1671
5743    23582
5749    20186
5779    11356
5783    27475
5791    3355
5801    25336
5807    14072
5813    1983
5821    3899
5827    8546
5839    5779
5843    13872
5849    12459
5851    3513
5857    12987
5861    17554
5867    2715
5869    1471
5879    3212
5881    316
5897    10
5903    355
5923    61
5927    34275
5939    17720
5953    2229
5981    731
5987    2253
6007    3297
6011    7142
6029    4763
6037    12352
6043    20779
6047    4995
6053    16184
6067    24673
6073    15689
6079    13949
6089    2346
6091    637
6101    8039
6113    4110
6121    9165
6131    4244
6133    5396
6143    4171
6151    2147
6163    3659
6173    24487
6197    42406
6199    8354
6203    14551
6211    3842
6217    42460
6221    36983
6229    184
6247    7408
6257    6929
6263    13511
6269    1870
6271    7373
6277    10545
6287    12246
6299    6036
6301    12635
6311    15705
6317    3308
6323    10683
6329    45502
6337    27215
6343    4301
6353    2367
6359    3312
6361    27658
6367    34186
6373    13472
6379    15054
6389    3052
6397    5262
6421    7603
6427    10992
6449    6341
6451    26198
6469    8968
6473    1374
6481    2386
6491    7009
6521    378
6529    37802
6547    4407
6551    8390
6553    6904
6563    10047
6569    8465
6571    4725
6577    11355
6581    21323
6599    26344
6607    15688
6619    8353
6637    12763
6653    6507
6659    211
6661    13594
6673    3746
6679    6009
6689    13351
6691    892
6701    13295
6703    12439
6709    7825
6719    2052
6733    505
6737    18391
6761    19529
6763    5429
6779    36081
6781    8153
6791    20702
6793    7155
6803    3104
6823    1040
6827    14663
6829    2641
6833    2839
6841    25009
6857    3910
6863    5417
6869    13312
6871    8165
6883    7094
6899    1061
6907    5131
6911    19897
6917    11503
6947    2507
6949    1295
6959    1117
6961    12131
6967    23792
6971    6194
6977    5136
6983    3876
6991    10760
6997    28101
7001    2338
7013    5746
7019    166
7027    556
7039    10108
7043    10177
7057    9233
7069    3383
7079    8841
7103    5325
7109    5595
7121    11940
7127    3425
7129    24632
7151    6617
7159    28648
7177    888
7187    2775
7193    8664
7207    5340
7211    756
7213    5671
7219    7303
7229    3401
7237    15503
7243    23524
7247    8811
7253    139
7283    4879
7297    770
7307    18345
7309    4005
7321    1622
7331    12649
7333    6916
7349    24243
7351    468
7369    10557
7393    16750
7411    11814
7417    15024
7433    23866
7451    2935
7457    12956
7459    10293
7477    740
7481    584
7487    4660
7489    2554
7499    8743
7507    8704
7517    4428
7523    577
7529    26762
7537    19083
7541    8516
7547    9072
7549    2177
7559    1516
7561    35013
7573    1959
7577    631
7583    8482
7589    3777
7591    8408
7603    16419
7607    5915
7621    3040
7639    5261
7643    9579
7649    6992
7669    591
7673    12831
7681    12769
7687    5573
7691    15649
7699    2069
7703    4859
7717    19934
7723    1630
7727    1591
7741    2212
7753    1545
7757    16195
7759    20016
7789    633
7793    12160
7817    8138
7823    1402
7829    4431
7841    38257
7853    2813
7867    232
7873    10153
7877    4141
7879    10319
7883    19514
7901    6668
7907    5662
7919    3356
7927    13760
7933    17728
7937    9119
7949    7109
7951    26711
7963    32202
7993    2795
8009    5069
8011    16218
8017    3417
8039    4131
8053    956
8059    10960
8069    5730
8081    10882
8087    25159
8089    4321
8093    3802
8101    11936
8111    152
8117    34924
8123    8155
8147    15919
8161    1650
8167    15447
8171    849
8179    13692
8191    2901
8209    52
8219    28328
8221    5149
8231    13603
8233    228
8237    11892
8243    1355
8263    32278
8269    35202
8273    6940
8287    10834
8291    3367
8293    5844
8297    1445
8311    15197
8317    14748
8329    27477
8353    5548
8363    15907
8369    9959
8377    6786
8387    862
8389    3878
8419    35
8423    11427
8429    6164
8431    13962
8443    3716
8447    3108
8461    9950
8467    581
8501    10737
8513    20121
8521    171
8527    10996
8537    677
8539    2814
8543    9608
8563    11164
8573    12417
8581    6511
8597    31178
8599    3568
8609    550
8623    2465
8627    1779
8629    4838
8641    7113
8647    20692
8663    9556
8669    11246
8677    14300
8681    19219
8689    2206
8693    19681
8699    3292
8707    753
8713    10306
8719    24174
8731    918
8737    69786
8741    2159
8747    2584
8753    872
8761    12672
8779    12248
8783    9373
8803    35681
8807    4285
8819    3028
8821    28327
8831    15196
8837    1822
8839    8524
8849    3559
8861    9441
8863    13198
8867    14299
8887    5871
8893    13243
8923    696
8929    11013
8933    4323
8941    10956
8951    2010
8963    3611
8969    5129
8971    4503
8999    17118
9001    11193
9007    10505
9011    8763
9013    17150
9029    9146
9041    10204
9043    20732
9049    1760
9059    3695
9067    4868
9091    247
9103    20817
9109    3404
9127    7997
9133    5606
9137    15242
9151    3463
9157    15066
9161    8199
9173    639
9181    15683
9187    6379
9199    13017
9203    8301
9209    328
9221    9478
9227    686
9239    12251
9241    29392
9257    11108
9277    1177
9281    3334
9283    7193
9293    3853
9311    844
9319    1164
9323    14
9337    75961
9341    1416
9343    34354
9349    34850
9371    2773
9377    3055
9391    11851
9397    4948
9403    7631
9413    1074
9419    13904
9421    3315
9431    2235
9433    399
9437    553
9439    11824
9461    3657
9463    529
9467    1240
9473    13291
9479    2508
9491    496
9497    14103
9511    13354
9521    5274
9533    1125
9539    2230
9547    19023
9551    6736
9587    6077
9601    6302
9613    5935
9619    1235
9623    16714
9629    14399
9631    794
9643    25892
9649    10539
9661    3090
9677    17746
9679    1804
9689    690
9697    34132
9719    26016
9721    1083
9733    15348
9739    21517
9743    15011
9749    55
9767    30386
9769    4701
9781    2625
9787    4140
9791    10120
9803    2477
9811    7761
9817    18966
9829    10067
9833    501
9839    2951
9851    20120
9857    3624
9859    3567
9871    10305
9883    14145
9887    9943
9901    11873
9907    4402
9923    8745
9929    19541
9931    22219
9941    1073
9949    7609
9967    27717
9973    21942
10007   187094
... ...
35023   4872
35027   156184
35051   304466
35053   216759
35059   29650
35069   116593
35081   51481
35083   73814
35089   226635
35099   83863
35107   387509
35111   68050
35117   306945
35129   301463
35141   76047
35149   109707
35153   71727
35159   23226
35171   50696
35201   25218
35221   93743
35227   49825
35251   67202
35257   12972
35267   104035
35279   90135
35281   181598
35291   10192
35311   5549
35317   38658
35323   38699
35327   26040
35339   47919
35353   6745
35363   7413
35381   5036
35393   107339
35401   70562
35407   86498
35419   68522
35423   82596
35437   12982
35447   5434
35449   50844
35461   86948
35491   94502
35507   3587
35509   61890
35521   12582
35527   95193
35531   87265
35533   213273
35537   54053
35543   108001
35569   715492
35573   93871
35591   11167
35593   2480
35597   20766
35603   19159
35617   389228
35671   245681
35677   49408
35729   29175
35731   103508
35747   3222
35753   164474
35759   82065
35771   43543
35797   34804
35801   56068
35803   89992
35809   20097
35831   96152
35837   65113
35839   212943
35851   87308
35863   161253
35869   230392
35879   137862
35897   9
35899   60382
35911   44703
35923   316672
35933   48204
35951   77313
35963   74046
35969   2753
35977   75346
35983   17292
35993   73761
35999   185659
... ...
95003   72804
95009   31377
95021   38327
95027   116014
95063   98208
95071   212974
95083   229554
95087   75241
95089   19544
95093   44277
95101   139328
95107   99727
95111   76649
95131   50614
95143   15018
95153   87203
95177   275120
95189   91800
95191   169225
95203   1048
95213   70154
95219   43923
95231   2736
95233   66016
95239   47738
95257   1004
95261   9114
95267   111683
95273   80739
95279   12183
95287   102543
95311   113902
95317   351750
95327   69661
95339   145724
95369   49909
95383   53494
95393   159916
95401   93599
95413   52017
95419   145652
95429   6030
95441   128413
95443   46728
95461   192477
95467   19734
95471   385281
95479   169002
95483   288650
95507   356737
95527   154844
95531   400772
95539   179271
95549   296724
95561   12006
95569   9618
95581   36823
95597   218735
95603   56615
95617   191466
95621   44455
95629   286144
95633   41106
95651   41437
95701   17180
95707   62494
95713   111881
95717   141674
95723   60493
95731   10322
95737   18219
95747   14961
95773   1064
95783   190374
95789   161486
95791   134673
95801   25335
95803   47314
95813   1982
95819   44821
95857   56375
95869   10757
95873   220166
95881   80081
95891   19571
95911   246039
95917   239538
95923   50672
95929   410470
95947   88426
95957   68614
95959   58900
95971   58902
95987   47926
95989   82878
96001   116326
96013   243724
96017   335258
96043   66895
96053   44364
96059   39793
96079   26235
96097   53056
96137   23761
96149   269672
96157   50319
96167   115671
96179   26269
96181   72996
96199   89012
96211   114140
96221   36982
96223   106890
96233   353856
96259   84422
96263   444601
96269   91394
96281   77780
96289   15057
96293   143600
96323   133279
96329   209317
96331   49076
96337   425599
96353   164639
96377   4806
96401   15881
96419   74292
96431   117493
96443   26625
96451   109544
96457   266506
96461   2144
96469   8967
96479   175640
96487   137966
96493   149229
96497   16516
96517   25430
96527   189483
96553   258033
96557   57540
96581   110217
96587   108192
96589   5113
96601   47077
96643   117896
96661   27702
96667   97500
96671   31672
96697   27004
96703   13182
96731   214646
96737   21352
96739   10474
96749   22557
96757   49301
96763   132131
96769   150586
96779   78010
96787   195551
96797   1804
96799   150510
96821   22257
96823   1039
96827   18476
96847   130469
96851   86899
96857   428540
96893   28651
96907   5130
96911   31278
96931   380393
96953   2755
96959   5577
96973   48857
96979   253065
96989   45989
96997   28100
97001   112287
97003   102560
97007   15732
97021   71517
97039   239534
97073   57942
97081   15444
97103   210050
97117   25229
97127   68112
97151   21047
97157   13626
97159   243238
97169   38
97171   126567
97177   140023
97187   103264
97213   135578
97231   357381
97241   88393
97259   6167
97283   28040
97301   72493
97303   6626
97327   23709
97367   18559
97369   126454
97373   104553
97379   181807
97381   30490
97387   23010
97397   34006
97423   14266
97429   49547
97441   281406
97453   22745
97459   10292
97463   3741
97499   8742
97501   189030
97511   23896
97523   70899
97547   32619
97549   2176
97553   192098
97561   250177
97571   44786
97577   14914
97579   21193
97583   8910
97607   116219
97609   17212
97613   64389
97649   53516
97651   7894
97673   144800
97687   273946
97711   92203
97729   2172
97771   62579
97777   1588
97787   14455
97789   47935
97813   260258
97829   114362
97841   94178
97843   35381
97847   46859
97849   370516
97859   21533
97861   253611
97871   154210
97879   53059
97883   164577
97919   46691
97927   111018
97931   142049
97943   330351
97961   23125
97967   176081
97973   157209
97987   164304
98009   110387
98011   124111
98017   75834
98041   99768
98047   30242
98057   154741
98081   180496
98101   53120
98123   235999
98129   562872
98143   164762
98179   187600
98207   33131
98213   193053
98221   59014
98227   113643
98251   100311
98257   74135
98269   35201
98297   15316
98299   95853
98317   39904
98321   30728
98323   94919
98327   22275
98347   96104
98369   366539
98377   312331
98387   2822
98389   3877
98407   74862
98411   343416
98419   148572
98429   10085
98443   29531
98453   46144
98459   134205
98467   160640
98473   66075
98479   90659
98491   8511
98507   29436
98519   139921
98533   167929
98543   229263
98561   97617
98563   74881
98573   22187
98597   31177
98621   44853
98627   35289
98639   21680
98641   7112
98663   129217
98669   187220
98689   247160
98711   396059
98713   10305
98717   18138
98729   208959
98731   120134
98737   149466
98773   131549
98779   89240
98801   16581
98807   52470
98809   20192
98837   16689
98849   27231
98867   28724
98869   139890
98873   154994
98887   44825
98893   141982
98897   28737
98899   265034
98909   394621
98911   28284
98927   196790
98929   11012
98939   6262
98947   132100
98953   9866
98963   49624
98981   132320
98993   376989
98999   17559
99013   66524
99017   11873
99023   69669
99041   10203
99053   60110
99079   4402
99083   149180
99089   38195
99103   83866
99109   176658
99119   1532
99131   134449
99133   58866
99137   240033
99139   388766
99149   71872
99173   54893
99181   71285
99191   16163
99223   246510
99233   30188
99241   273129
99251   148361
99257   277042
99259   90424
99277   47040
99289   13893
99317   198464
99347   25420
99349   105134
99367   196341
99371   6312
99377   82069
99391   11850
99397   4947
99401   43168
99409   43810
99431   83069
99439   298692
99469   75121
99487   60700
99497   14102
99523   58542
99527   12182
99529   116130
99551   167603
99559   290581
99563   29308
99571   408050
99577   1063
99581   1981
99607   7774
99611   235248
99623   23152
99643   67099
99661   3089
99667   31476
99679   150509
99689   159487
99707   156856
99709   61677
99713   68127
99719   113693
99721   146719
99733   101902
99761   63186
99767   89359
99787   64128
99793   40267
99809   58930
99817   47762
99823   3570
99829   99444
99833   21580
99839   2950
99859   195326
99871   65783
99877   89239
99881   52828
99901   66523
99907   266371
99923   104298
99929   33452
99961   142413
99971   56781
99989   9962
99991   17988
```

---

Prime numbers under $1,000,000$: the farthest prime number $805289$ has distance $11\:137\:824$.

---

If consider any $5$-digital sequences, then the farthest one is $33394$ with distance $1\:369\:560$ 
($\approx$ $2$ times farther than prime number $35569$).

Any $6$-digital sequence: the farthest one is $569540$ with distance $14\:118\:307$ 
(see [Pi Digits](https://bellard.org/pi/pi2700e9/pidigits.html) for more info).

---

(for **Peter**'s request:)

to generate complete list (of n=100000 of n=1000000 items), I used simple C++ code. 

Short description:

- load decimal digits of $\pi$ (assume we have them in text file, downloaded or generated before) to text string;
- make array which marks whether certain number is prime (any Sieve of Eratosthenes implementation);
- convert numbers to strings, and apply substring search in main string;
- one can decorate the code to save the farthest (prime) number entry etc.

The code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

const int n = 100000;   
const int pi_size = 10000000;

void applyEratosthene(bool *prime, int n){
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)  prime[i] = true;
    prime[0] = prime[1] = false;
    for (int q=2; q*q<n; q++){
        for (int k=2; k*q<n; k++){
            prime[q*k] = false;
        }
    }
}

void loadPi(char* pi, int size){
    std::ifstream f("pi-digits.txt",std::ios::binary);
    f.read(pi,pi_size);  pi[pi_size]=0;  f.close();
}

int main(){
    char* pi = new char[pi_size+1];
    loadPi(pi, pi_size);

    bool *prime = new bool[n];
    applyEratosthene(prime, n);

    char number[16];
    for (int x=1; x<n; x++){
        if (!prime[x])  continue; // comment it to see not primes-only entries
        std::sprintf(number,"%d",x);
        std::cout << x << "\t" << 1 + strstr(pi,number) - pi << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please add more details : Which program did you use, the code of the program , ...

Comment: @Peter: the C++ code is added. simple substring search.

Answer (score 2):

A Perl snippet to do this:

```
$ perl -Mntheory=:all -E 'my $pi = substr(Pi(1000000),2); my($mi,$mp)=(0,0); forprimes { my $i = 1+index($pi,$_); ($mi,$mp)=($i,$_) if $i > $mi; die $_ unless $i; } 100000; say "last seen: $mp at $mi";'

last seen: 35569 at 715492
```

Takes about 2.5 seconds on my Macbook so about the same time as Oleg567's C++ code takes if we count the time for Pi digits.  I am sure Pari/GP could do it similarly.  We conveniently have a function that returns lots of digits of Pi in a reasonable time, a way to loop through primes, and the index function to find the first position of a substring.

It also found 805289 at 11137824 when searching the first 1M, matching Oleg567's result.  That took 2.5 minutes on my Macbook, which is, unsurprisingly, about the same time as the C++ program plus Pi generation.